# Is there any limit on the amount of data Freemarker can render?

Tags: java, freemarker, stripes

I am using Freemarker with Stripes. In one of the cases where I have a table to render which has 17 columns and some 13-15 rows, the whole of it is not getting rendered at once. There is no error/exception being thrown, just the last part of the table is getting truncated and a series of dots (...) appears.

Is this default behavior? Can the size of data to be rendered be increased from somewhere? I am totally stuck with this one.

Comment: some times exceptions are not thrown on page check the logs you'll probably find exception thrown

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker itself has no input data or output size limit. I suppose you are using some special directive to render that table, and that directive implements this limiting. Showing how you render that table might helps.